# azure app registration redirect uri not working for a spa application but only for one server

Tags: windows, iis, authentication, entra-id

m a little stumped on this and just wondering if anyone had any ideas.

I have registered in azure an application with 3 spa redirects It is a .net core react application

http://localhost:3000/eem/ (local dev) https://xxxxxx:4388/eem/ (development) and https://apps.axxxxxxxxxege.edu/eem/ (prod)

the dev and development work perfectly the user is redirected to office 365 login and then after they authenticate they are returned to the redirect url and continue.

but in production https://apps.axxxxxxxxxege.edu/eem/ they go to the office 365 login they authenticate but then I get a url with the redirect url and then /#code= and my access token and it throws a 404 error

server team assured me that iis is set up identically for dev and prod (of course I have no visibility of that)

I've been troubleshooting for days but I can't figure it out does anyone have any ideas where to troubleshoot?

here is the url I get back with the 404

https://apps.axxxxxxxe.edu/eem/#code=0.ATgAb3x1E5-EDE-Y4CZfLU3Q1veLWXji-xNLqweOC3lqZyU4AAA.AgABAAIAAAD--DLA3VO7QrddgJg7WevrAgDs_wUA9P9zmmwofVpH1E2KtSIjdcvW3pB1DQg-0gXvKav4ScQxFLOfhsdmaSxu81pJMClR8PJLH73yc03m-wCOSAfJZtwnzXR_Mq76jaxiJ_kHME6Kk76HkFp_1cQDG99ztIcFPrIShjHhI36-DjQ7jz_lJ5WqPWTRCDfL5Y-pzhsWcUY_5z_gxqyby09ozd3cgiPqY5kNFszhf2JiljIH895GK3cIWA_460Er8KfnoG6Xji5TB_fJ8oqAniaaKXKH2mSwqZBZpzMbNLwWImTeFCZVNMno1Jbb-xHaSEPXLHEFzuW-ZJPA1XEOBLwX5t4dSeEo-TeZ1id4drN5yXyFHJCzjusdU6OX88xCrhNnp3N3cGdufYURsHQlrcGlcHsVZmY8a-TF0fdrpmIv_frgRy5-1NDVwsLPp8mY7pmEUP_jYdg9uy2SfCvuXLMFEbh6polvyK0NY06wwjJx8w7PFpmnX3bSQxNpy5PaEezlvPk7_q-FBSGDUCbUqUaA43q1QwymvLQSG4mmajLCdm9Gy8_VERVsWqg1CWdRu2kmLygf7tFKxhDkG3Kl_UE36aCPY0M2JuDKUQEri5f3umvKsXKQgTwu_NlDswKGontxZ10dWj9HlW05WT-2TLSORZ6bX_C0K2Cm2cMeX6xIPqg08HonIJO5Oyqayh0KiKqhoofad6Zs8QacoH-GgY7rNPpXhJrToM2VrBfK11mP7MjEOjqST1xbbyPCwLGU7YsDO_Ahq6Okd7Gv81d2WSPhuHewRZ2KjJYD1ewqsN2xQk_blFjDnQKTgy9NWQNbAIO68yrqTfjMcBBcLlJ_a9fXpnJob3pyZ4ZYOqxkOhYfh6LVBnsBDB8XOL5XLNS9GgK31Lb9GPZG_zHtt6SlxLpFr3joh1XsbpkkzbM9Q1sTyEbZu3ictaJ6h7lkjgmU12V1CShiO7U3nV3pjwYTTcNKvU3Phbn2BwrzL7rFdxg2HRbbWLSPTm7ha1I&client_info=eyJ1aWQiOiI3MGNkOWE4Yy01OTg5LTQ0MDctODMxYy03YjcxNjRlYzUxODAiLCJ1dGlkIjoiMTM3NTdjNmYtODQ5Zi00ZjBjLTk4ZTAtMjY1ZjJkNGRkMGQ2In0&state=eyJpZCI6IjBlNDA3NjZmLTMwMTMtNDg4Mi04NmM1LWYxMzRjN2U2ZTg2MSIsIm1ldGEiOnsiaW50ZXJhY3Rpb25UeXBlIjoicmVkaXJlY3QifX0%3d&session_state=b925b84a-845b-42eb-a14b-7e1b205845d6

just wanted to add I added 2 new redirects to the spa azure registration and put the code on two other development servers and they both work flawlessly the office 365 login comes up they authenticate and it goes back to the react application.

I don't really have any visibility of the production server (windows 10 running iis for a .net 6 c# app with the react application in the wwwroot folder) I am not allowed access to the server but are there any suggestions I could give to the server team they are not huge fans of troubleshooting and just tell me that everything is the same. I am not sure where in the authentication flow the problem is occuring.